# XQuery/eXist : get a list of a specific attribute?

Tags: xml, xquery

I have the following XML file :

```
<animals>
   <animal id="1" weight="56">Flipper</animal>
   <animal id="2" weight="230">Dumbo</animal>
   ...
</animals>
```

And I only want to keep the weights (so it returns "56 230..."). I tried this request :

```
//animal[@weight]
```

But I still get the entire XML content... I also tried :

```
//animal/@weight
```

And with that I get this error :

> Error SENR0001: attribute 'weight' has no parent element

What's the tip ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as if your XQuery engine is expecting to return one or more XML documents; since attribute nodes can't appear at the root of an XML document it is unhappy.

You might try (1) writing the query to return not the attribute nodes but only their values:

```
for $w in //animal/@weight
return string($w)
```

If your engine really only ever wants to return XML documents, then (1) won't make it happy, either.  So you might then try (2) returning a sequence of XML elements:

```
for $w in //animal/@weight
return <weight>{$w}</weight>
```

If that doesn't make *you* happy, you can (3) wrap the string you want in an XML wrapper:

```
<weights>
{ for $w in //animal/@weight return string($w) }
</weights>
```

and if you want each on a separate line, (4)

```
<weights> { 
  "&#xA;", 
  for $w in //animal/@weight 
  return (string($w), "&#xA;")
} </weights>
```

Comment: `//animal/@weight/string()` should do the trick without the explicit for-loop.